# Too many dml rows exception

Tags: trigger, batch

I tried to insert records for call__c object which gives this exception

Trigger:

```
trigger trgInsertCall on Call__c (after insert) {

    Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>(); 

    for(Call__c ca:Trigger.new)
    {
        clientIds.add(ca.Client__c);
    } 
    if(trigger.Isinsert)
    {               
        Database.executeBatch(new batchableClass(clientIds),10); 
    }              
}
```

Batch class:

```
global class batchableClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();    
    list<Id> clientIdList = new list<Id>();
    String searchString='';
    list<String> searchList=new list<String>();   
    list<Call__c> callList = new List<Call__c>();    

    global batchableClass(Set<Id> clientIdSet) { 
        clientIds = clientIdSet; 
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {    
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            [Select Id,Client__c,Note__c 
             FROM Call__c 
             where Id IN:clientIds]
        );      
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call__c> scope)
    {
        if (scope.isEmpty())
            return;
        for(Call__c ca:scope){       
            if(ca.Is_Checked__c==true){                       
                object__c[] objectList=[Select object__c 
                                        from object__c 
                                        where Client__c IN:clientIds 
                                        AND object__c LIKE '%abc'];
                if(objectList!=null && objectList.size()>0){
                    for(object__c obj:objectList){
                        searchString=((String)(obj.object__c)).Substring(0,5);                                                     
                        if(searchString!=null){
                            searchList.add(searchString);
                        }                       
                    }
                }              

                for(String searchValue:searchList){
                    String searchExp = searchValue.Replace('*', '%') + '%';                      
                    Account[] ObjClientList=[Select Id 
                                             from Account 
                                             where Id IN (SELECT Client__c 
                                                          FROM object__c 
                                                          WHERE ObjectSearch__c LIKE:searchExp 
                                                          AND (NOT(object__c LIKE '%_abc'))
                                             )];  

                    if(ObjClientList!=null && ObjClientList.size()>0){
                        for(Account act:ObjClientList){                           
                            clientIdList.add(act.Id);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(clientIdList!=null && clientIdList.size()>0){    
                    for(Integer i=0;i<clientIdList.size();i++){                               
                        Call__c calls = new Call__c();                     
                        calls.Client__c= clientIdList[i] ; 
                        calls.Note__c=ca.Id;
                        callList.add(calls);                                               
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        insert callList; 
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

Comment: Use Database.executeBatch(new batchableClass(clientIds),1); and let us know if you still get the error.  My guess is that you have too many related objects.  I don't consider this a good fix, but it could give a little more info.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of working with only up to 10 `Call__c` objects passed in to the `execute` method via the `scope` parameter, you are executing a query using the full set of IDs here:

```
Select object__c from object__c where Client__c IN :clientIds
```

and as these are probably child objects of `Call__c` the number of records involved is likely to be very large.

(You are also querying `Account` inside a loop which is a dangerous thing to do as you could hit a governor limit there too.)

Ideally you should re-arrange your `Batchable` to be passing `Object__c` in the scope rather than `Call__c` so that the numbers of objects involved is defined. You may be able to do that by changing to using a [relationship query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) that queries both `Object__c` fields and parent `Client__c` fields:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{  
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
            Select Object__c, Client__r.Id, Client__r. Client__c,
                    Client__r.Note__c, Client__r.Is_Checked__c
            from Object__c
            where Client__c IN:clientIds 
            AND Object__c LIKE '%abc'
            ]);
}
```

Comment: Object__c is not child of Call__c.  Object__c and Call__c are child object of account.

Comment: @Lipali In one place you have `FROM Call__c where Id IN:clientIds` and in another you have `from object__c where Client__c IN:clientIds` that suggests a relationship between the two objects. But bottom line is that you need to find a way to limit the volume of data within each call of the `execute` method.

Comment: Both the objects are child objects of Account.   Client__c is a lookup field(with account object) in both the objects(Call__c and object__c)